# How to get distance from google distance matrix Api in Java

Tags: java, json, google-distancematrix-api

I am trying to find the distance and time between two places using google distance matrix api
Everything was fine until I got this Data

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [
      "Some Address"
   ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Some other address" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "13.1 km",
                  "value" : 13133
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "33 mins",
                  "value" : 1961
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I tried to extract distance using Json libraries and tried many answers too,but dint get the expected result ,Any help??

Comment: Can you please share problem details about parsing json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is a complete answer of how to calculate distance and time with google distance matrix api between two places.
If you are not using maven then you have to set these jars in your classpath

pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okio/okio -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
    <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.0</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is a class to send http request and get the data in json format

```
 package google.distance.api;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

@Component
public class DistanceTime {



    private static final String API_KEY="YOUR KEY";
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();


public String calculate(String source ,String destination) throws IOException {
String url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="+source+"&destinations="+destination+"&key="+ API_KEY;
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().string();
          }


}
```

As I am using Spring ,so here is my Controller method to get the data

```
private DistanceTime distance;

     @Autowired
    public void setDistance(DistanceTime distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}


    public ModelAndView Api(@RequestParam("picking_up") String source,@RequestParam("dropping_off") String destination,@RequestParam("pick_up_date") String time) {
            try {
                  //method of DistanceTime Class
                String response=distance.calculate(source,destination);

            System.out.println(response);
            }

            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception Occurred");
            }

            return new ModelAndView("home");

        }
```

Now the Tough Part was iterating over JSON data to get the distance and time
  In the  above method I was getting json data in variable  response ,so here is the code to extract distance and time from it
The response was something Like

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [
      "Private"
   ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Private" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1,052 km",
                  "value" : 1051911
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "17 hours 10 mins",
                  "value" : 61785
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}



 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {

         Object obj = parser.parse(response);
         JSONObject jsonobj=(JSONObject)obj;

         JSONArray dist=(JSONArray)jsonobj.get("rows");
         JSONObject obj2 = (JSONObject)dist.get(0);
         JSONArray disting=(JSONArray)obj2.get("elements");
         JSONObject obj3 = (JSONObject)disting.get(0);
         JSONObject obj4=(JSONObject)obj3.get("distance");
         JSONObject obj5=(JSONObject)obj3.get("duration");
         System.out.println(obj4.get("text"));
         System.out.println(obj5.get("text"));

    }
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse json you can  use json libraries in Java like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson),[Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) [Json simple](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple).
Second way(i would recommend) you can create you own Java request and response beans according to json request and response from API and use them in  http requests ,you cand find full example from [here](https://gitlab.com/samiragayarov/distanceMatrixDemoInJava)

```
package com.apartmentnotification.client;

import com.apartmentnotification.model.DirectionResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;

public class ApartmentClient {

private static final String BASE_URI = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api";
private static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyCXnwOwrv_Kt7bkbO5vXtpPelu08yp-3iY";

/**
 * end point for read distanceMatrix
 */
private WebTarget distanceMatrix;

public ApartmentClient() {
    Client client = LazySingleton.getClient();
    distanceMatrix = client.target(BASE_URI + "/distancematrix");

}

public DirectionResponse getDirectionInfo(String origins, String destionations) throws IOException {
    return distanceMatrix.path("/json")
            .queryParam("units", "imperial")
            .queryParam("origins", origins)
            .queryParam("destinations", destionations)
            .queryParam("key", API_KEY)
            .request()
            .get()
            .readEntity(DirectionResponse.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ApartmentClient wc = new ApartmentClient();
    DirectionResponse direction = wc.getDirectionInfo("Vaidavas 6/3", "Domina Shopping");
    System.out.println("Duration in hours :"+direction.getRows().get(0).getElements().get(0).getDuration().getText());
    System.out.println("Distance  in metr : "+direction.getRows().get(0).getElements().get(0).getDistance().getValue());
}
```

}

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using Java client library :

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33078974)